# DatePicker setEditable to false still allows for clicking of Calendar

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, calendar

I am currently trying to setEditable for a DatePicker to false so the value cannot be changed. Using the following only disables the text field, but still allows the changing of the date by clicking on the calendar button (the setEditable is for permissions, so I can enable/disable depending on the login):

```
exampleDatePicker.setEditable(user.getGroup().equals(admin));
```

**Is there a way to disable the Calendar button on the DatePicker?** I don't want to use setDisable, as I still want the field to be readable, and I can't change the CSS for disabled because I have other DatePickers that get disabled that I want greyed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable it (i.e make it behave like it's disabled), call `setDisable(...)`:

```
exampleDatePicker.setDisable(! user.getGroup().equals(admin));
```

To change the appearance from the default disabled look (which I agree is very hard to read), you can still use CSS, but choose this `DatePicker` specifically. The easiest way is probably to use a CSS pseudoclass:

```
PseudoClass notAuthenticated = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("not-authenticated");
exampleDatePicker.setDisable(! user.getGroup().equals(admin));
exampleDatePicker.pseudoClassStateChanged(notAuthenticated, ! user.getGroup().equals(admin));
```

and then in your external CSS you can set styles for `.date-picker:not-authenticated`, e.g.:

```
.date-picker:not-authenticated, .date-picker:not-authenticated > .text-field {
    -fx-opacity: 0.85 ;
}
```

I would recommend making the date picker look a little different from a truly active (not disabled) date picker, or else it may be confusing to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, as stated above, I want to avoid disabling the whole field, as I want it to still be readable despite the user being unable to edit it.

Comment: You want it to act like it's disabled, but look like it isn't disabled?

Comment: See update. You can still use `setDisable(...)` and CSS, you just need to be trickier with the CSS selector.

Comment: Making the Calendar Button disappear when the DatePicker is not enabled for editing would probably be the best solution visibly.

Comment: That's what I thought I would have to do in the end. Will play around with that. Thanks.

Comment: You *should* be able to do something like `.date-picker:editable > .arrow-button { visibility:  visible;}` and `.date-picker > .arrow-button {visibility: hidden;}` but I can't quite get it to work...

Comment: Found a semi-solution: `exampleDatePicker.lookup(".arrow-button").setDisable(!user.getGroup().equals(admin));` after the window has been launched. However, like you said, there may be confusion if it is still visible. Using `setVisible(user.getGroup().equals(admin))` makes the button disappear but leaves the grey area still there, and doesn't look good.

Answer (score 6):

For future searches, here's what I did:

```
dtpDate.setDisable(true);
dtpDate.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1");
dtpDate.getEditor().setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do it:

```
yourDatepicker.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        if(yourDatepicker.isDisabled && yourDatepicker.isShowing())
            yourDatepicker.hide();
    });
```

This way when you click on it, the popup won't show ;)
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
datePicker.setEditable(false);

datePicker.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        if(!datePicker.isEditable())
            datePicker.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I was confused in this issue. Finally I found that elegant way to resolve:

```
yourDatepicker.getEditor().setDisable(true);
```

Well, just get editor of your datepicker and disable it!